# update map with another map

Tags: dictionary, groovy

In groovy, I want to update (left merge) a map with another.

```
def item = [attributes:[color:'Blue', weight:500], name:'hat', price:150]
def itemUpdate = [attributes:[size: 10]]
item << itemUpdate
println item
```

Gives:

> [attributes:[size:10], name:hat, price:150]

But what I want is:

> [attributes:[color:'Blue', weight:500, size:10], name:'hat',
>   price:150]

I have also tried:

```
item += itemUpdate
```

or using [Updating groovy object fields from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618719/updating-groovy-object-fields-from-a-map).
None fulfils my requirements; in *python* the method would be the `update()` method.

*Edit*: I'm wrong about python actually.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Yes, it's a duplicate, although I did not phrase my question properly. The "recursive" aspect generalises better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is effectively overwriting the `attributes` entry.

What you want to do, instead, is:

```
item.attributes = item.attributes + itemUpdate
```

You can even do:

```
item.attributes += itemUpdate
```

Both of which yield the expected

```
[attributes:[color:Blue, weight:500, size:10], name:hat, price:150]
```